# Should I prefer ->> or @>

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

In postgreSQL on a JSONB column I can run two queries with the same (?) result.

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b->>'c' = 'lorem';
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b @> '{"c": "lorem"}';
```

In term of performance and semantic (and maybe some other consideration I don't see here), what query should I use to search "the items from `a` where `c` is `lorem`"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on [what indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) do you have or want to add (if you want to use an index at all). And  what other queries you want to execute on the `jsonb` typed column.

```
WHERE b->>'c' = 'lorem'
```

queries will benefit from index(es) on the `(b->>'c')` *expression*, while

```
WHERE b @> '{"c": "lorem"}'
```

queries will benefit from a GIN index on the `(b)` *column*, but not the other ways around.

The first form will likely result in a smaller, and more effective index, but will only work for this special case. If you want to query other properties of `b` too, the GIN index can be more helpful.

If you don't want to use indexes at all, it's really just a matter of taste.

*Sidenote:* the solutions above work a little different, when dealing with `NULL`s:

```
WHERE b @> '{"c": null}'
```

will select rows if, and **only if** the `c` property has a JSON `null` value in it, while

```
WHERE (b ->> 'c') IS NULL
```

will select rows if the `c` property has a JSON `null` value in it, **or** the `c` property is not defined in the row at all.

Also,

```
WHERE (b ->> 'c') = NULL
```

won't select any rows, because of the standard compliant handling of `NULL`s (the expression `(b ->> 'c') = NULL` is always evaluated to `NULL` -- or `UNKNOWN` within the `BOOLEAN` type --, which is always *falsy* in the context of `WHERE` predicates).

Comment: BTW `(b ->> 'c') IS NULL` is equal to `(not b ? 'c' or b @> '{"c": null}')` where `?` operator also supported by GIN index.

Comment: @Abelisto yes, exactly. It's just a little clumsy workaround. But I doubt that a lot of people need to worry about edge cases like this. I just mentioned because this is the only difference between these 2 methods (if OP doesn't want to use indexes).

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of taste which solution looks better to you, you be the judge there. They look about the same to me.

When it comes to performance, I suggest that you test it yourself.
Write a `DO` statement in PL/pgSQL that performs the same operation 100000 times in a loop, then use the `psql` command `\timing` or something similar to see how long it takes. Repeat the tests several times to check if the result is reproducible. Chances are that the difference, if any, is lost in the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Came with same idea as Laurenz. And despite the number of top key-value pairs, they seem to perform same:

```
 t=> do
t-> $$
t$> declare
t$>   _i int;
t$>   _j jsonb;
t$> begin
t$>   with n as (select generate_series(1,9999,1) g) select concat('{',string_agg(concat('"a',g,'":22'),','),',"c": "lorem"}')::jsonb into _j from n;
t$>   for _r in 1..999999 loop
t$>     select 1 into _i where _j @> '{"c": "lorem"}';
t$>   end loop;
t$> end;
t$> $$
t-> ;
DO
Time: 2406.016 ms
t=>
t=> do
t-> $$
t$> declare
t$>   _i int;
t$>   _j jsonb;
t$> begin
t$>   with n as (select generate_series(1,9999,1) g) select concat('{',string_agg(concat('"a',g,'":22'),','),',"c": "lorem"}')::jsonb into _j from n;
t$>   for _r in 1..999999 loop
t$>     select 1 into _i where _j->>'c' = 'lorem';
t$>   end loop;
t$> end;
t$> $$
t-> ;
DO
Time: 2799.750 ms
```